# Pandas sampling Dataset randomly base on the sum of columnn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sample

I have dataframe that I would like to sample **randomly** like `df.sample(n=13250)` but base on one condition that the sum of the columns x *(dtype=float)* isn't over 12000.

Any idea of how to process?

I try `df[df['x'].sum() <= 12000].sample(n=13250)` but with no success

```
ark|typedoc|planographic|intaglio|relief|photosensitive|monochrome|colors|x
btv1b7700367s|True|False|False|False|True|True|False|3.0
```

In my example `ark` is my unique id all columns are of type `bool` except column x.

To be more clear on the context, the id corresponds to a document and each document can have a possible number of pages from 1 to 455 represented in the `x` column.

I want to create a sample of this dataset which contains a maximum of 12000 pages and not 12000 documents as a document can have many pages.
One last thing I don't want to restrict the number of documents to a single page because I need to have a fairly representative population with documents from min() to max()

Comment: It's difficult to sample with conditions as you can either pre-filter some values or use trial and error. The exact method(s) will depend on the data. Can you provide a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: I added context and one rows as an example

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the original dataframe, add a cumulative page count column, then take as many rows as needed before the cumulative number of pages exceed 12,000:

```py
sample = df[df["x"] <= 12_000].sample(frac=1)
sample = sample[sample["x"].cumsum() <= 12_000]
```

Thanks to @mozway suggestion, the answer was updated to only sample for documents with 12,000 pages or less. This prevents cases where a large document (12,001 page) get shuffled at the top of the sample, which causes empty selection.

Comment: Nice one (+1), but not always optimal. For instance let's assume one row has the value 12001 and randomly happens to be the first row after `sample`, this would give an output with no rows while a "better" sampling could be achieved. That's always an issue with sampling with conditions and OP should be careful of that and know the pitfalls.

Comment: @mozway thanks for raising that edge case. That can be eliminated by filtering for only documents with 12,000 pages or less

Answer (score 0):

My first shot as a newbie trying to answer questions to get better :

```
def sample_docs(df):
sample_subset=pd.DataFrame([[]])
total_page = 0
while total_page < 12000:
    df_ = df.sample()
    sample_subset = sample_subset.append(df_)
    total_page = sample_subset['x'].sum()
return sample_subset
```

Seems to work but clearly :

- unoptimized (looping when vectorization seems more appropriate like shown by @Code Different)
- using append method, which is deprecated. Using concat would be better here
- same drawbacks as previously said by @mozway : the sampling can give an incorrect feeling for the data. Maybe using quantiles while sampling could be done.

Comment: What about the problems that (1) you are sampling with replacement here (so the result may end up containing duplicates), and (2) without additional restrictions added to your code, the result may still end up containing more than 12K pages, as you are checking the page count *before* sampling?